# How can I measure power being supplied to connected usb devices to my desktop in .NET C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I am in need for measuring power that is being supplied to all connected usb devices respectively. They are connected to my PC. I would like to use .NET and C#.

I searched google for this. Some suggested to use WMI, but I could find only how to get list of connected usb devices and being notified when connected/disconnected.

I couldn't find out how to measure power (amperage) supply and adjust amperage by using WMI. So I thought WMI is not enough to do this. Is there any other method to find this out?

Comment: There is no current sensor built into USB hardware.  You need a ammeter, not software.  http://academic.pgcc.edu/ent/ENT%20171%20Online%20Project/fluke-mm.jpg

Comment: During the connection/initialisation phase, USB devices are required to specify the *maximum* power they can use. It may be possible to obtain these values programmatically (OS's must store the value somewhere to ensure the maximum bus power cannot be exceeded), but the instantaneous power usage is not part of the USB spec.